# Code to reduce execution time by array / caching??? Google App Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, caching, google-sheets, execution-time

I'm using the following code to compile a list of hastags which have been seperated from a list of twitter tweets.

This code ignores all rows where the hashtag cell has no value or an error value.

```
function CopyProcessedHashtags() {

  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("SortedIntoRows");
  var targetSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("HashtagsList");
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cell = sourceSheet.getRange("E" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
      if (val != "") {
      if (val != "#VALUE!") {
      if (val != "#REF!") {

        var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("B" + i + ":" + "E" + i);    
        var targetRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
        targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetRow+1);
        var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("B" + (targetRow+1));
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  }}}}}
};
```

The trouble is that there is sometimes thousands of rows and execution time is well over 6 mins.

I know batching can reduce execution time...

EXAMPLE

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(i);

to

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(i, 100);
```

... I just don't know how to rewrite my code to work in this manner.

Still very new to google app script.

If somebody could give me a nudge in the right direction you'r help would be VERY much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getValues()` to retrieve all data within the range and filter it using `Array.filter()`.

**Example:**

**Code:**

```
function CopyProcessedHashtags() {

  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("SortedIntoRows");
  var targetSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("HashtagsList");
  
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredData = data.filter(dataRow => (dataRow[4] != "#VALUE!" && dataRow[4] != "#REF!" && dataRow[4] != ""));
  targetSheet.getRange(1,1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
}
```

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Perfect. Over 2000 rows from 20 odd mins to under 2 seconds!